# Create function to use in ode45

Tags: matlab

[image: This is part of a larger project]

So this is part of a larger project but I am stuck on number two of this section. I rewrote the system to get it in the required form:

dx(1)/dt = x(2)

dx(2)/dt = (-(M+m)/mL))x(4) + 1/(mL)u

dx(3)/dt = x(4)

dx(4)/dt = -(mg/M)x(1) + (1/M)u

After substituting the variables given in the problem I wrote the funcion:

```
function dx = fun(t,x)
dx = zeros(4,1);
dx(1) = x(2);
dx(2) = -((2+.1)/(.1*.5)).*x(4);
dx(3) = x(4);
dx(4) = -((.1*9.81)/2).*x(1);
end
```

I am confused on how to implement u(t) = 0 and how to create the theta function.

Any help even if its just pointing me in the right direction would be amazing. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. You implement `theta` as another state. This is possible since you know the derivative, which does not even depend on the other states. To be more precise, you should add two more states here. One for `theta` and one for `theta_dot`.

```
dx(5) = x(6)  % Theta'
dx(6) = -0.1  % Theta''
```

And by the way, you can also pass additional variables to your differential equation. You just add more arguments to it

```
function dx = diffeq(t,x,parameters)
  ...
end
```

and create a new function handle where you execute the ODE solver

```
[T,X] = ode45(@(t,x)diffeq(t,x,parameters),t_span,X0, ode_options);
```

This is just a hint since you're using [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in your differential equation function.

Comment: Thank you that helps a ton :) but how can I plot theta(t) vs time? Also does u(t) = 0 essentially means to disregard the u part of the system? I know how to plot x(t) versus time but if you add those states how can I only plot theta(t) versus t?

Comment: @ Chloe Carmichael for the time being, yes, you ignore `u(t)` completely. Although I guess it will no longer be ignored in a later part of your project. How you'll handle it then depends how u is given. If it's an external function you can simply use it in your differential equation and pass the time as a parameter: `u = funct_u(t)` and then use `u` in your differential equation.

Comment: Also you should already define `u` now and simply set it to zero. The way you formulated your equations now `u` is completely missing, which is mathematically seen not wrong, but code-wise it is. `u` is there, it's just `0`.

Comment: As for plotting theta(t) vs t, theta corresponds to the fifth column of your X matrix. X and T are returned by your ode45, it's all there already. If you still can't see it post your complete code please and we can have a look.

Comment: @ potAito Using the above function to plot x(t) 
`>> tspan = [0 5];
init = [.01 -.1 1 2];
[t f] = ode45(@fun,tspan,init);
plot(t,f(:,1),'-',t,f(:,2),'-.',t,f(:,3),'.',t,f(:,4),':')`
If I try implementing your function I get index out of bounds.

Comment: @ChloeCarmichael 
 
I think you are passing you init vector in a wrong way. You don't need to pass it to the differential equation fun, it corresponds to X0 in my example in the answer. Consider editing your question with all the code you're using instead of wiring it in the comments, much easier to read ;)